# delete image with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I want to delete the old image from images folder when I update the product in NodeJS, product is updating, but old image is not deleting from the folder.

index.js

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(cors())
app.use('/', route)
app.use('/images', express.static('images'))
```

function

```
export const updateProduct = async (req, res)=>
{
    try{
        let image 
        const oldProduct = await Product.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
        const {name,price,quantity,category} = req.body
        
        if(req.file)
        {
         image = req.file.filename
         const oldImageUrl= `/images/${oldProduct.image}`

          // this is url of the old image http://localhost:2001/images/1629969633380_r.png

         await  fs.unlinkSync(oldImageUrl)

        }else{
            image = oldProduct.image
        }
        const productToUpdate = new Product({name,category,quantity,price,image})
        await Product.updateOne({_id:req.params.id},productToUpdate)
        
         res.status(200).json('product Updated')
     }catch(error)
     {
         res.status(404).json({message:error.message})
     }
}
```

Comment: I have had this issue before, try killing your app and launching it again.

Comment: `fs.unlinkSync(oldImageUrl)` doesnt return a promise

Answer (score 1):

Based on this bit of code:

```js
app.use('/images', express.static('images'))
```

You should try to delete the image relative to the app folder.

```js
const oldImageUrl= `images/${oldProduct.image}`
```

Or even better yet, use the `path` module.

```
const { join } = require('path');
...
const oldImageUrl = join(__dirname, 'images', oldProduct.image);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/update/:id', upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
        let data = {
            name: req.body.name,
            price: req.body.price,
            quantity: req.body.quantity,
            discount: req.body.discount,
            discription: req.body.discription,
            file: req.file.filename
        }
        const oldProduct = await products.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
        const result = await products.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, data,);
        fs.unlink('./public/image/' + oldProduct.file, function (err) {
            if (err && err.code == 'ENOENT') {
                // file doens't exist
                console.info("File doesn't exist, won't remove it.");
            } else if (err) {
                // other errors, e.g. maybe we don't have enough permission
                console.error("Error occurred while trying to remove file");
            } else {
                console.info(`removed`);
            }
        });
        res.redirect('/listProducts');
    })
```